# Unable to find ChirpConnectNative for Windows UWP

Tags: chirp

I am unable to find windows[UWP] **ChirpConnectNative** library in your documentation or downloads pages. Please guide me where can I find that?

[Chirp Windows documentation](https://developers.chirp.io/docs/getting-started/windows) [Downloads page](https://developers.chirp.io/downloads)

Answer (score 2):

I'm Damien and I am working at Chirp. The chirp SDK for Windows UWP is currently in private beta. To get access to it you can reach us from the contact form on our website (https://chirp.io/contact) referencing this discussion and I'll give you access to it.

When the SDK will be publicly release I will edit this post to complete the answer.

Cheers,
Damien